# How to add a constraint to check if the date entered (column) is today's date

Tags: mysql

I was having this "database" exam and I bumped into the following question.

Alter table "x" to add a constraint that only lets you enter today's date in "x.datecolumb".

I clearly have no idea how to do so, so ...?

Comment: Do you even have any thoughts as to what the answer might be? Have you searched? If so, what were the results?

Comment: A constraint is supposed to be true at all time, unless your rows only exist for 1 day it does not make sense to declare such constraint. A trigger can validate that the row is correct when it is inserted. Besides, MySQL does not "support" check constraints AFAIK.

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits the core features of table and column CHECK constraints, for all storage engines: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

In all MySQL versions

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

[MySQL Reference Manual, CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

The only way to solve Your problem seems to be a trigger pack checked constraint You need and discarded wrong data insertion. But this solution is not complete - there is a lot of situations when inserting/altering data do not fire the trigger action.